# Azure Landing Zone: What are all the BuiltInRoles to be assigned? Especially for Management Groups, Subscriptions, Vnets, Gateways, VMs, SA, SQL

Tags: azure

Currently, I am working on establishing enterprise-scale landing zones for Cloud Adoption Framework in Azure.

Azure has a list of BuiltInRoles defined as mentioned in this article - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles.

It is unclear to me which role should be assigned to which resource

Especially for the below Resources

- Management Groups
- Subscriptions
- Vnets
- Gateways,
- VMs
- Storage Accounts,
- SQL databases

Can you suggest what are all the Roles should be assigned while provisioning any of the above listed Resources?

Comment: I would suggest you use a tool like Terraform or Bicep, or if really needed ARM. to deploy a CAF infrastructure. It is too complex to manage by hand, mistakes are easily made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cloud Adoption framework is not about putting some roles on some arbitrary resources. You have to look at the framework in terms of [hierarchical levels](https://aztfmod.github.io/documentation/docs/fundamentals/lz-intro/#the-levels-approach). Each hierarchical level has its own purpose and therefore uses its own set of permissions to deploy the resources needed for that particular step. I referenced some role mapping templates from **aztfmod** (Terraform + CAF) so that you get an idea about the role/permission structure.

- Level 0: Core platform automation

  - Billing subscription role delegation ([source](https://github.com/Azure/caf-terraform-landingzones/blob/5a9f9ac59b5a8c349dc79d5c8703951f87fa6518/templates/platform/level0/billing_subscription_role_delegations/subscription_creation_roles.tfvars.j2))
  - Credential role mappings ([source](https://github.com/Azure/caf-terraform-landingzones/blob/5a9f9ac59b5a8c349dc79d5c8703951f87fa6518/templates/platform/level0/credentials/role_mappings.tfvars.j2))
  - Launchpad role mappings ([source](https://github.com/Azure/caf-terraform-landingzones/blob/5a9f9ac59b5a8c349dc79d5c8703951f87fa6518/templates/platform/level0/launchpad/role_mappings.tfvars.j2))
- Level 1: Core platform governance
- Level 2: Core platform connectivity

  - ASVM role mappings ([source](https://github.com/Azure/caf-terraform-landingzones/blob/5a9f9ac59b5a8c349dc79d5c8703951f87fa6518/templates/platform/level2/asvm/role_mappings.tfvars.j2))
- Level 3: Application landing zones vending machine
- Level 4: Applications landing zone

If you understand the levels correctly, you are able to infer what permissions are needed at what stage of the deployment of the CAF framework. For example:

- level 0 is initiated by a user that is tenant administrator and Enterprise Agreement (EA) user, besides it needs to be the owner of the initial "launchpad" subscription.
- From there this user will create service principals for each of the other stages of the deployment, and delegate permissions according to the principle of least privilege.
- Key vaults and key vault policies are used to exchange sensitive information like credentials in between steps.
- Each platform step (automation, governance, connectivity) is then run by its own service principal with its own specific set of permissions set on a specific scope (management group, subscription, resource group).
- When all the platform components are in place you’ll be able to provision custom landing zones. Where you’ll again create service principals that are scoped to a single subscription. These service principals are able to deploy resources only within that landing zone.
- Etc.

I would **not** recommend setting CAF or the permissions by hand, because it will become a pain in the ass to maintain. You could for example use **aztfmod** a Terraform implementation of CAF. If you follow the steps as described [here](https://aztfmod.github.io/documentation/docs/azure-landing-zones/landingzones/alz-intro), you'll create terraform configuration to deploy a CAF setup.

[image]